# MatPlotLib Plot last few items differently

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm exploring MatPlotLib and would like to know if it is possible to show last few items in a dataset differently.

Example: If my dataset contains 100 numbers, I want to display last 5 items in different color.

So far I could do it with one last record using annotate, but want to show last few items dotted with 'red' color as against the blue line.

I could finally achieve this by changing few things in my code.

Below is what I have done.

Let me know in case there is a better way. :)

```
series_df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

series_df = series_df.fillna(0)

series_df = series_df.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=True)

# Created a new DataFrame for last 5 items series_df2

plt.plot(series_df["Date"],series_df["Values"],color="red", marker='+')
plt.plot(series_df2["Date"],series_df2["Values"],color="blue", marker='+')
```

Comment: Please add a minimal code example to further understand your question

Comment: I could do this by slicing the DataFrame and calling plot twice. Updated my code as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some minimal code example or a figure with the desired output to make your question clear. It seems you want to highlight some of the last few points with a marker. You can achieve this by calling `plot()` twice:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.arange(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[-5:], y[-5:], ls='', c='tab:red', marker='.', ms=10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with what I have done.